# wrong version of pygame installed or not installed correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, macos-catalina

When I want to run a game I programmed, I get the error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I had problems installing pygame on my iMac (OSX Catalina). I have python 3.8.

From the command line I achieved installing pygame with:

pip3 install --user pygame

So what to next:

Check if I have the correct pygame version installed?
Does it matter where I install pygame?
What could be the reason of the error message?

My game worked on my MacBookPro but I had to give it away because of a damage. I remember, that I had to install some different version of pygame (some development version), because I couldn't install the normal one.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem now. python3 -m pip install --user --pre pygame=2.0.0-dev6 worked for me.